# Cannot make edits to published mvc website on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have published a website on IIS server and am accessing it over the company network. The website is located in Inetpub / wwwroot.

I never had any problem updating the project through Visual Studio. Today I added a new Controller and Model to the project which runs absolutely fine on localhost but does not run on the server.

Can any one guide me towards what i am potentially doing wrong and how to correct this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Check if the IIS_IUSRS group has write access to Inetpub / wwwroot

Comment: @AlexOvechkin Yes it does. It make edits all the time and they reflect just fine. I think its not taking edits that i made by creating a new Model and a Controller.

Comment: can you provide more details? You got an exception, smth else?

Comment: I found something that is very similar to what i need-----> "If you upload the view (.cshtml) file and that is the ONLY part of the application that has changed, a refresh will reflect the change - you may have to ctrl+f5 to clear the temp cache. However! If you change ANY of the controller code or action code, or any c# (or vb if thats what you use), then you MUST re-upload the compiled .dll associated with the entire application in order for the changes to be reflected."--------- How do i re-upload my .dll to IIS? Thanks.

Comment: How do u publish your solution to production? You can try to choose 'release' and if u got remote access to your server just copy files and see if it helps